# How to track GPS device using GPRS connection

Tags: c#

I want to track my GPS device using gprs connection, which should give details like speed of the vehicle, location, time etc. Can please some body help me how to write this function in c# code or any idea regarding this would be great full.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8128/Writing-Your-Own-GPS-Applications-Part-I), probably [this](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm), and maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529).

Good luck!

It wouldn't hurt to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) as well. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.                                                 I dont need a code for console application.This is how my GPS device works.. My GPS device sends its coordinates to my server via GPRS connection, the configuration of GPS device is done by manufacturer. Now I should write a server side script which should receive coordinates from my GPS device and then map its position in google maps using Latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a COM Interface, I hear that MS provides one too but I am not sure if there are already applications delivered that use it if their owners are not MS personels.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I dont need a code for console application.This is how my GPS device works.. My GPS device sends its coordinates to my server IP via GPRS connection, the configuration of GPS device is done by manufacturer. Now I should write a server side script, which should receive coordinates from my GPS device and then map its position in google maps using Latitudes and longitudes.